# Прошу помочь упростить код (js)

Tags: javascript

Имеется функция, которая при отправке какой либо команды, получает ответ:

```
var
input = document.getElementById('main_input');
output = document.getElementById('main_output');

function enterCommand() {
  if (input.value in cList) cList[input.value]();
  else out('error:  ' + input.value, 'no');
  input.value = '';
  scroll();
}
```

cList выглядит следующим образом:

```
var cList = {
  command1: function () {
    out('command1');
  },
  command2: function () {
    out('command2');
  },
  command3: function () {
    out('command3');
  };
};
```

Все команды появляются в маленьком dive с id `div_output` (в `div_input` команды вводятся)

В моем случае, команд для обработки будет очень много, и я не хочу для каждой из них писать отдельную функцию, тем самым расширяя код до невозможности. Я знаю, есть пример куда легче, но сам я не смогу разобраться. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, буду благодарен, если кто даст ответ.

Comment: Хм. А _что_ вы хотите, чтобы произошло? Для некоторых команд не должно быть вовсе никакой функции, или некоторые функции могут обрабатывать несколько схожих команд?

Comment: Я хочу упростить код, но дело в том, что все команды должны быть выполнены, т.е должен последовать ответ за ней. Врядли у меня будут функции, которые будут обрабатьывать схожие команды, все они разные.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так, например

```
var cList = [ 'command1', 'command2', 'command3' ];

function enterCommand() {
  if (cList.indexOf(input.value) >= 0) {
    out(input.value);
  } else {
    out('error:  ' + input.value, 'no');
  }
  input.value = '';
  scroll();
}
```

Comment: Ваш код работает, но мне нужна функция, которая по команде 'command1' , получал ответ ввиде некого сообщения, как тут: 

`command1: function () {
    out('command1');
  },` 

Либо, на крайний случай, оставить мой код так, как есть, но вынести все функции в отдельный файл. (если это будет правильным с точки зрения программирования и не костыльно)